# Function to get an email notification if a cell is changed to include today's date?

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

Looking to get an email notification if any cell in a google sheet is changed to include today's date, in EITHER FORMAT such as 6/7 or 6/7/16 .

New to this, and I searched heavily but am confused on editing functions.

Also for this, should I use onEdit as the trigger?

Any help is greatly appreciated<3

Comment: Edit OP to include the function you're trying to edit. Is this excel or google sheet?

Comment: whoops!  google sheet

Answer (score 0):

As you are going to use a MailApp class (or GmailApp class), you have to use an installable trigger, because normal spreadsheet triggers (onEdit, onChange) do not work with classes that need authentication.

With installable `onChange` or `onEdit` trigger there's no easy way to know which cell was changed. You can't just do:

```
function myOnChange(event){
  event.range; // To get the modified range.
}
```

That's a limitation. ([simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/), [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable))

I have a quite similar problem, but the cells I'm monitoring are in a specific column. I look though the column to see if I find the content I want and then I call other functions if that's positive.

Take a look at this code and adapt this to your case. Its pretty close!

```
function onEditTrigger(){
  if(todaysDateIsOnTargetColumn()){
    sendMail('recipient@example.com', 'Subject', 'replyto@example.com', '<p>text</p>' );
  }
}

function todaysDateIsOnTargetColumn(){
  var range = getSheetByName('Your Sheet Name').getRange('A1:A'); // in fact, here you can use the range you want!
  var todaysFormattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(Date.new(), "GMT", "dd/MM/yy");
  return foundMatchingValueOnRange(range, todaysFormattedDate); // This function will see if the value (today's date) is inside the range.
}

function sendEmail(recipientEmail, emailSubject, emailReplyTo, emailHtmlBody) {
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: recipientEmail,
    subject: emailSubject,
    replyTo: emailReplyTo,
    htmlBody: emailHtmlBody
  });
}

// Utils (these can be useful in other projects)

function foundMatchingValueOnRange(range, value){
  var foundMatchingValue = false;

  var uniqColumnValues = flatten(range.getValues()); 
  var valueIndex = uniqColumnValues.indexOf(value)

  if(valueIndex >= 0){
    foundMatchingValue = true
  }

  return foundMatchingValue;
}

function flatten(matrix){
  return [].concat.apply([], matrix);
}

function getSheetByName(name){
  var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(name);
  return sheet;
}
```

Then, after that, you have to install the trigger on the sheet:

On the Script edition page, got to Resources > Current Project's triggers and do:

[image]

I know that's not exactly what you're looking for, but google spreadsheets have some restrictions when it comes to triggers and permissions working together!

Hope that helps!